# Oracle and MySQL date column format

Tags: mysql, oracle

So i just curious about this , is it "just because Oracle different than MySQL" or i am doing something wrong here

i just notice that the date that i sent from my client computer translated into a different format in Oracle Database it goes like (22-JUL-18) 
meanwhile in MySQL it written as (2018-07-22)

here is the picture [MYSQL Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAeKo.png) , [Oracle Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXaU.png)

Comment: This is just a presentation thing.  If you're looking at the same date in both databases, this is the important thing.

Comment: what was the query used? date format shown are most likely due to formatting in the query.

Comment: July vs 06 - is this just a typo?

Comment: Those screenshots seem to show different client applications. Different applications are free to present things in whatever format they like. Perhaps there are display preferences you can adjust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference you see is because of the default date format of Oracle and MySql are different. 
Oracle's default format for DATE is "DD-MON-YY", whereas for MySQL the default date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Of course, this is not how they are stored in the database internally (which also varies)

Oracle Default Date Format Reference - http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html
MySQL Default Date Format Reference - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html